# token.php - Class 'Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken' not found

Tags: php, ios, twilio, twilio-php

Someone Help me out of This, I'am Unable to Get AccessToken when I run The file **token.php** In My terminal.
When I run it In the terminal I'm getting an error like this:

> /token.php - Class 'Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken' not found in /Users/xxx/Desktop/GETFolder/token.php on line 26

```
  <?php

    include('./vendor/autoload.php');
    include('./config.php');
    include('./randos.php');



        use Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken;
        use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\IpMessagingGrant;

    $appName = 'ChatQuickstart';
    $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID='xxxxxxx';
    $TWILIO_API_KEY='xxxxxxx';
    //$TWILIO_API_SECRET='xxxxxxxx';



    $identity = "NAYEEM";
    $deviceId = $_GET['device'];
    $endpointId = $appName . ':' . $identity . ':' . $deviceId;

    $token = new AccessToken(
        $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
        $TWILIO_API_KEY,
        $TWILIO_API_SECRET,
        3600,
        $identity
    );


    $grant = new IpMessagingGrant();
    $grant->setServiceSid($TWILIO_IPM_SERVICE_SID);
    $grant->setEndpointId($endpointId);
    $token->addGrant($grant);

    echo json_encode(array(
        'identity' => $identity,
        'token' => $token->toJWT(),
    ));
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the [Twilio PHP Library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php)? Where have you stored it on your machine?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, where following the instructions in the quickstart have produced the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late but I hope to help someone in the future who is coming across this. For me I had to use

```
composer require twilio/sdk
```

Afterwards I ran

```
composer dump-autoload
```

You should see a file within your "[PROJECT-FOLDER]/vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/Jwt/AccessToken.php